# Polymer change custom-style variable at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, shadow-dom

I have an application where i want to change the whole theming at runtime. I define the primary colors in my custom-style tag like so:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  /* Application theme */
  :root {
    --dark-primary-color: #3b280a;
    --default-primary-color: #FDB815;
    --light-primary-color: #fdd85f;
  }
</style>
```

Would it be possible to apply other values for these variables later? 
I tried adding a new custom-style file by appending

```
<link rel="import" href="../styles/other-style.html">
```

to the head, but it does not work. I think polymer interprets that at the begining, right? I am now thinking about not using custom-style at all and wrapping my whole app in an element where i can set the styles with variables, but that seems like a lot of work, maybe someone got any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this manually

```
 this.customStyle['--my-toolbar-color'] = 'blue';
    this.updateStyles();
```

see the documentation [part](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-api)